# ASP.NET JavaScriptSerializer Deserialize not returning results

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization

I am posting to my client's new API, which is returning:

```
{"status":{"statusCode":1,"errorType":2,"errorCode":9000,"errorMessage":"System could not process your request"}}
```

Note: the returned JSON contains '\"'

In my C# Code I define a structure:

```
public struct userStatusStruct
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public int errorType { get; set; }
    public int errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in C# using

```
 loginResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
 ....
 var streamResponse = new StreamReader(loginResponse.GetResponseStream()
 ....
 var result = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();
```

I receive a statusCode.OK.
the result string is above:  Then Deserializing it into the Struct with:

```
 var vs = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataClass.userStatusStruct>(result);
```

The deserialize userStatusStruct contains 0 and string.empty.

I've done this many times before but this one I'm stumped why it's not deserializing the result into the structure format.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid for `userStatusStruct`, you need to define another class which contains `userStatusStruct` as a property:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public userStatusStruct status { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Deserialize` JSON to `ApiResult` and you can get `status` as follow:

```
var apiResult = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataClass.ApiResult>(result);

var vs = apiResult.status;
var statusCode = vs.statusCode;
//the other properties
```